# Fetch distinct values from column in file to create RDD

Tags: pyspark

I am new to Pyspark. I need to find distinct values from a certain column in an RDD.

I have a comma delimited .txt file with no column headers on S3.

```
    rddDistinct = sc.textFile(fileLocation).map(lambda x: x[2])                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    print rddDistinct.take(10)
```

What am I doing wrong? Eventually, I would like to store the resulting RDD in S3 (haven't gotten there yet). If the file exists in S3, I would like to overwrite it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `.distinct()` after your `map` function.

```
rddDistinct = sc.textFile(fileLocation).map(lambda x: x[2]).distinct()
print rddDistinct.take(10)
```

Comment: that didn't work for me for some reason. Instead I tried the following and it worked. `sc.textFile(fileLocation).map(lambda x: x.split(",")[2]).distinct()`

Comment: You did not have a reproducible data sample. I had to assume you were knowing what you were doing till that step (i.e. You were picking up the right element with `x[2]`)